# Get outlet size within awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, objective-c, awakefromnib

I created a custom `UICollectionViewCell` containing an outlet for a label (placed in the Storyboard). I'd like to get the height of this label from within the `awakeFromNib` method of my custom `UICollectionViewCell`, but the size of the label is always `0.000000`:

```
// .h
@interface MyCustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@end

// .m
@implementation MyCustomCell

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.myLabel);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.myLabel.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.myLabel.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

Console output:

```
2013-02-06 11:13:59.628 Test[8880:c07] <UILabel: 0x7649a00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = '12h00'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7649ac0>>
2013-02-06 11:13:59.628 Test[8880:c07] 0.000000
2013-02-06 11:13:59.630 Test[8880:c07] 0.000000
```

How can I get the size of my label ?
Is it too soon to get such information when `awakeFromNib` is called ? If so in which method of my custom cell should I get the size ?

**EDIT**

Here is the same strange behavior observed in the ViewController:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.myLabel);
}
```

And the output:

```
2013-02-07 16:07:34.488 Test[30308:c07] <MyCustomCell: 0x7156980; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (20 0; 290 655); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7156a80>>
2013-02-07 16:07:34.489 Test[30308:c07] <UILabel: 0x7158100; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'this is a text'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7158040>>
```

Comment: Documentation says that: _“When an object receives an `awakeFromNib` message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.”_ Make sure you have connected outlet. Try logging those two in `prepareForReuse` or other methods. If they are still zero, problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The value is correct when logged in `prepareForReuse`, but this is far too late for what I intend to do with this value. I'd like to draw a line using the height of my label, and this line should be visible (and correctly placed) when the cell is created.

Comment: And what about `self.myLabel`? Is this outlet already set in this `-awakeFromNib`?

Comment: I edited the question, see first line of the console output

Comment: I saw this behavior only once: `textLabel` of `UITableViewCell` has zero frame until the cell is displayed. But since this is `UICollectionViewCell` and the label is created by you in XIB, I really don't know why it has no frame.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A part of the answer is in dreamzor's response to [iOS AutoLayout - get frame size width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527191/ios-autolayout-get-frame-size-width).

> The trick is to place your frame-dependent code to the viewDidLayoutSubviews method

In my particular case, I found that adding `[self layoutIfNeeded];` in my custom cell `awakeFromNib` method, right before asking for the outlet size worked like a charm.

Comment: Can I give you more than a +1??? I was having trouble setting the layer corner radius. I wanted a round shaped UIButton and I was using self.layer setCornerRadius:self.bounds.size.width/2.0] but it was looking awful until I used your trick of adding [self layouIfNeeded] just before that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the optimal solution but to make some changes on subviews or getting information like you do, I create a method on the subview like "prepareSubviews" or "refresh" or "populateWithData". After initializing/ loading view from IB, I invoke that method inside "viewDidLoad", at that point the xib file should be loaded and working properly.

Comment: XIB should be fully loaded at the point of `awakeFromNib` so I think the problem is somewhere else.