# draw a colored circle in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to generate a UITableViewCell with a colored circle on the left.
My plan is to use UIButton and manipulate its layer's corner radius.
However, the colored button never appears.

My xib:

[image]

I have an IBOutlet to my ColorHolder UIButton and a variable for its color.

```
class ColoredCircleCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorHolder: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoRow1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoRow2: UILabel!

    var circleColor: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor 

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        colorHolder.layer.cornerRadius = colorHolder.bounds.size.height / 2
        colorHolder.layer.backgroundColor = circleColor
        colorHolder.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

In my cellForRowAt indexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CircleCell", for: indexPath) as! ColoredCircleCell

        print(cell.colorHolder.bounds.size.height)

        cell.colorHolder.layer.cornerRadius = cell.colorHolder.bounds.size.height / 2
        cell.colorHolder.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        cell.infoRow1.text = "H1"

        return cell
    }
```

The console tells me  that the size of the cell is 1000. I'm guessing it still has not resized with respect to the row height.

**EDIT**: I've narrowed down the problem to `cell.colorHolder.layer.cornerRadius = cell.colorHolder.bounds.size.height / 2` . The value of `cell.colorHolder.bounds.size.height` is always 1000. How do I extract the correct value AFTER it has been rendered to the screen?

The output:

[image]

How do I add a configurable circle for my UITableViewCell?

Comment: Check the constraints of button that may be issue.

Comment: Is the size of that button dynamic? Can't you just hardcode the cornerRadius?

Comment: yes, the intention is to make the size of the button dynamic. a hardcoded cornerRadius would definitely make my life easier though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting the answer here for completion's sake.
I had to add `self.layoutIfNeeded(`) prior to accessing the bounds.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726810/get-outlet-size-within-awakefromnib) helped me out.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.layoutIfNeeded()   

        colorHolder.layer.cornerRadius = colorHolder.bounds.size.height / 2
        colorHolder.layer.backgroundColor = circleColor
        colorHolder.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your set colorbutton constraint like
topspace to superview and bottomspace to superView.

If that's the case than remove bottomspace to superView and add height constraint.

than do this

```
cell.colorHolder.layer.cornerRadius = cell.colorHolder.bounds.size.height / 2
cell.colorHolder.clipToBounds = true
```

and it should display as circle.

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just override `layoutSubviews` and set your corner radius there.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.colorHolder.layer.cornerRadius = self.colorHolder.bounds.size.height / 2;
}
```

Comment: tried it and got the same problem. I added a println statement above the line for cornerRadius print("the height: \(colorHolder.bounds.size.height)"). i kept getting height: 1000. thanks for suggesting it though

Comment: Can you also check the size of the cell in the same place?

Comment: sure. it's returning 89.95