# view's frame is all zeroes when using NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

After programmatically applying constraints to a view, I'm finding it difficult to use that view's frame - all values are zero.

I know that I can implement frame-dependent code in the view *controller* via `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - within that method, the frame has been set. But I'd rather not use a view controller for what I'm trying to do. Is there a similar method that fires in UIView? Or a notification? Something must call `viewDidLayoutSubviews`...

I've found related answers ([best one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14147303/869838)), but haven't been able to find an answer to this specific question.

Comment: In what method are you trying to access the view's frame?

Comment: Have you tried `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess layoutSubviews is the guy... I was hoping to get a sort of notification when a view's frame was available - so I could know from outside the view. But I could always implement that by overriding layoutSubviews and sending a notification, then calling [super layouSubviews]; Thanks for the replies!