# Hide button in stackview break the layout in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have a tableviewcell which has two button inside stackview. One of the button name is topupButton and the other one is details button. Topupbutton hidden if one flag is true. You can find below the code.

```
  self.topupButton.isHidden = self.selectedSim.operator_?.is_prepaid ?? false
```

When I hide the topup button details button should stretch in stackview. But in one of my cell, it's not in correct size. When I do visual debug I saw that the frame of button is correct but background is not stretch through the button. You can see the image's below.

[image: Two button cell]

[image: What I want when hide the topupbutton]

[image: When I hide the button]

I've tried layoutsubviews, setneedsdisplay, layoutifneeded for cell, stackview and buttons. Nothing changed. You can also find my stackview config below.

[image: Stackview config]

[image: Constraint of stackview]

[image: Constraint of stackview]

[image: Layout of cell]

Comment: I've added the constraint between the stackview and the contentview @nayem

Comment: It seems the constraints are correct. Did you use any kind of `CALayer` on the buttons?

Comment: I've used UIBezierPath for round the button corner. I did layer.layoutIfNeeded, layer.layoutSublayers, layer.setNeedsLayout but it's not solved @nayem

Comment: Can you try if the other button fills the stack view or not by commenting out the `UIBeizerPath` related code?

Comment: Yeap if I remove the code it's working perfectly. But I need rounded corner button :) @nayem

Comment: I've solved with give corner radius with self.layer.cornerRadius. Thank you @nayem !

Comment: Well, that's good that you have a solution already. But you can keep your `UIBeizerPath` related implementation. Look at the answer I made below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, it's evident that the usage of `UIBeizerPath` created the issue in the first place. It's because:

> Auto-Layout works best with `UIView`. But layers don't auto-resize.

Look at [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303279/auto-layout-constraint-on-calayer-ios) for more on the above lines.

---

As you are likely adding mask layer to the buttons, you need to find the ideal method for that addition of mask layer. And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443738/3687801), the correct place would be [draw(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw). So basically you will do something like below:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    . . .

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        topupButton.roundButton()
        detailsButton.roundButton()
    }

    . . .

}

// extension for rounding button with UIBezierPath
extension UIButton {
    func roundButton(){
        let size = CGSize(width: bounds.width / 2, height: bounds.width / 2)
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
                                    cornerRadii: size)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```