# read UI correct frame with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController` with `UIScrollView` inside. The scroll view automatically adjust its frame according with device screen.
My problem is that in the code I can't read the correct frame of scroll view. 
`self.scrollView.frame` always return `{{0, 0}, {600, 600}}` that's the default size of view controller in Interface Builder xib.

I have tried in `viewDidLoad` and in `loadView` methods but the frame is still `{{0, 0}, {600, 600}}`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.frame));
}
```

Ideas ?

Comment: Probably calling it before AutoLayout has run. Post your code

Comment: Edit. How can I sure AutoLayout has finished ?

Comment: It's too early in viewDidLoad. Try in viewDidAppear

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS AutoLayout - get frame size width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527191/ios-autolayout-get-frame-size-width)

Comment: I think you can use `self.view.bounds` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the correct frame in the `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` methods of your viewController

Comment: It works but `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called twice. Instead `viewDidAppear` is called once

Comment: this method is called n times where n is the number of the view layout.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you need correct frame after apply  layout constraints 
 write below two lines

```
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```