# Get size of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button, created in storyboard and linked in my .h using

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *gridLabel;
```

I'm trying to find out how big it is inside the viewDidLoad of my .m. For this I use

```
_gridLabel.bounds.size.width
```

But this always gives out a fixed number, no matter how big the button actually is. How can I make it work?

I am also getting the size of the screen using

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
```

and this seems to work. So can I do something similar

```
[[something _gridLabel] bounds].size.width
```

If so, what is the something?

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` there is no correct bounds. Try `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS AutoLayout - get frame size width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527191/ios-autolayout-get-frame-size-width)

Comment: Thanks to both. viewDidLayoutSubviews seems to be working.