# How to add constraints for UIImage in dynamic cell only after auto layout has drawn the view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, autolayout

I'm trying to draw a circular image in a tableview cell. I have figured out how to draw the circle when the image is in a normal view: I place this code in viewDidLayoutSubviews () so as to apply my changes to the image only after autolayout has done its thing.

```
 profilePicture2.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture2.frame.size.height/2
    profilePicture2.clipsToBounds = true
```

I got that tip from this answer: [Why does adding an align with centre constraint to a UIImage throw out the radius of corners setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956387/why-does-adding-an-align-with-centre-constraint-to-a-uiimage-throw-out-the-radiu/35956415#35956415)

But how do I do it if the image is in a dynamic tableview cell? Is there a way to use viewDidLayoutSubviews() for a single cell, so I can set the corner radius of my image AFTER autolayout has done its thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom class for profilePicture which extends UIView and override `layoutSubviews`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2
}
```