# How to get the height of a view that has been stretched by constraints? - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have following view hierarchy:

- Root View

  - Child View

The root's height and width have been stretched by constraints (Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing) and should be about 500. The height of the child is set by constraints too, so it should also equal 500.

Everything looks fine visually, but when I access the frame.bounds.height of the child it returns me the height of the whole screen, rather than the estimated 500. Even worse, when I access the frame.bounds.height on the Rootview it returns me 0 because I have set the frame to .Zero.

My question now is, how can I get the width and height from a view, that has been stretched out by constraints? It seems to me that .frame.bounds does not work with autolayout.

Showcase:

```
    print("collectionView height: ", String(describing: collectionView.frame.height) )
```

> cv height:  0.0

CollectionView is the brown view:

[image]

My main objective was to make a cell as big as the brown collectionView. But this failed because I could not get the width of the dynamically sized collectionView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS AutoLayout - get frame size width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527191/ios-autolayout-get-frame-size-width)

Comment: Have you tried removing the `bounds` from `frame.bounds.height`? Also, *where* are you looking for this? `viewDidLoad`? That's too early - try `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: lthe4kman all answers are outdated because this question is more than 6years old

Comment: @dfd Hey, thanks for your answer. I am trying this in viewDidLoad. I will try it in viewDidLayoutSubviews now

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I was working on this so long! Thank You.

Comment: @dfd: it looks like your answer was the right one. Would you post that as an answer proper, so you can get the credit for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it looks like I helped solved the issue. It gets down to the view controller "life cycle", and exactly when "frames" are known".

The *abbreviated* lifecycle is:

- viewDidLoad
- viewWillAppear
- viewWillLayoutSubviews
- viewDidLayoutSubviews
- viewDidAppear

A simple check - using the console and/or breakpoints - of this will show a few things:

- while `viewDidLoad` knows of bounds, it know nothing of frames.
- `viewWillLayoutSubviews` *may* know of frames, but it's **also** called (usually) more than once.
  `-`viewDidLayoutSubviews` while *possibly called more than once, is the earliest moment for a "guarantee" of frame size.

I was asked to post this as an answer, but I was looking for better sources here. I found two - and *both* are part of the same question.

[UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle#12608364)

The top three answers are all good (I prefer the third for the best match to this question.)

For this issue, it gets to knowing when you can be sure frame size is known. It's possible that `viewWillLayoutSubviews` may work, but if it works, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the best place for this.